# Pipe echo return value

Tags: c++, unix, echo

I was curious to know if the return value of a CPP file could be piped into a file or echo'd. Is this possible and if so how?

**Here is a minimal CPP file**:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    return argc;
}
```

**Here is what I attempted to pipe**:

```
g++ foo.cpp
./a.out | echo
```

**However the result (nothing) is the same as**:

```
echo "" | echo
```

Comment: you want ./a.out; echo $?

Comment: @amdixon, both `./a.out | echo $?` and `./a.out 1 | echo $?` result in `0`

Comment: @asimes this is usually called `exit status`. For example, after `ls -l /tmp`, echo $?` will print zero `0` after `ls` output to indicate normal status. But `ls -l /not-exist; echo $?` will instead print `2` when the file does not exist.

Comment: You can't pipe anything to `echo`.  (Well, you can, and `echo` will blissfully ignore it.)  Perhaps you are looking for `{ ./a.out; echo $?; } | cat`.

Comment: I didn't know about `echo $?`, it was what I was looking for after `./a.out`